# Search engine that not only considers public transport and flights but also options like car sharing (e.g. BlaBlaCar) and renting a car?

Tags: budget, car-rentals, flight-search-engines, ride-sharing

This would be pretty helpful for people travelling on a tight budget in order to find the cheapest option to get from A to B. Example: Going to the next biggest city with an airport by car sharing and then taking a cheaper flight from there to your destination.

Comment: Apparently [rome2rio has ridesharing now](https://www.rome2rio.com/blog/2014/03/31/european-travel-costs-to-fall-as-rideshare-arrives-on-rome2rio/) but I've never seen it as an option for any route so I don't know if it's any good

Comment: Citymapper within a city does this, but it doesn't do city-to-city travel.

Comment: Which continent/country? And what level of car sharing, the kind of Uber and alike, for which you pay or the hitch-hiking kind where you pay part of the petrol money?

Comment: @Willeke it says Blablacar in the title, so that's like private motorists selling empty seats on planned personal journeys, not Uber-style 'informal taxi'

Comment: How would a search engine plan BlaBla Car rides? Analyze the current ridesharing offers on the market? Or just add a BlaBla price estimate?

Comment: @JonathanReez The same way search engines probably get their information on flights: Poll the airline websites and extract info like departure/arrival time, price and so on.

Comment: @Willeke In my case Europe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Rome2Rio can do it](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris/Nantes) for BlaBlaCar:

[image]

It doesn't do direct estimates for car rentals, but you can search for rental prices on the same page.